# How would you go around freeing a binary tree struct in C

Tags: c, free

I have a simple tree struct

```
  struct Node{
    struct node *l;
    struct node *r;
    int value;
  };
```

How am I supposed to free such a struct as a simple free(node) won't work due to it having 2 pointers inside. Will I have to transverse the entire tree starting from a given root and then free its left,right and then finally itself? Is this how I should tackle this problem?

```
  void destroy_tree(struct Node *node){
    if(node->r != NULL){
      destroy_tree(node->r);
      free(node->r);
    }
    if(node->l != NULL){
      destroy_tree(node->l);
      free(node->l); 
    }
    free(node);
  }
```

Comment: You are freeing the child-nodes *twice*.

Comment: Would "Yes" be a sufficient answer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah yes. How did I not see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete nodes in the order of postorder traversal. 
First delete left node/ right node then rightnode/leftnode and then root.

```
void del(node *root)
{
  if(root)  // if(root!=NULL) checking if root is null
  {
    del(root->left);
    del(root->right);
    free(root);
  }
}
```

Your code follows the same idea but I have shown a cleaner way.

```
void destroy_tree(struct Node *node){
    if(node->r != NULL){
      destroy_tree(node->r);
      free(node->r); ----> redundant
    }
    if(node->l != NULL){
      destroy_tree(node->l);
      free(node->l); -----> redundant. You have already deleted it.
    }
    free(node);
  }
```

You are basically following the postorder traversal.

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP is describing.

Comment: @ScottHunter.: I have given a clear answer. I will point the small error in OP's code now. Thanks for checking

Comment: @ScottHunter.: Please check my answer now.

Comment: @Bula.: check my answer

Comment: @coderredoc I'm sorry but I don't understand why you need an `if` statement checking for a root

Comment: @Bula.: This checks `if(root!=NULL)`. And then we don't need to enter it. That's why. IF `root=NULL` then if() will never be true.

Comment: @coderredoc Ah right. It's eliminating my two `ifs` . So then, there is no simpler way? I need to transverse over the entire given tree and check if it's in use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using recursion and use the backtracking phase to delete the nodes (hence from leave nodes to the root). So you are using the backtracking in a clever way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the tree freeing each node. Something like this -

```
deallocate (node *root){
       if (root==NULL)
       return;

   //now onto the recursion
   deallocate(node->l)
   deallocate(node->r)

    free(node);
 }
```

In your code you `free` node two times which is not needed.